# Why won't 'Promote' link appear on posts on a particular Facebook page?

Tags: facebook-pages

I have one page at http://facebook.com/trelloapp that, when I use Facebook as the Trello user, shows a 'Promote' link on all my posts:

[image: Promote link on Trello page]

But when I switch to use Facebook as Fog Creek Software and go to the Fog Creek page at http://facebook.com/fogcreeksoftware, none of the posts show up with a 'Promote' link:

[image: Fog Creek Facebook page no promote link]

My account is a 'Manager' on both pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Fog Creek Software Page](https://www.facebook.com/fogcreeksoftware) has 285 likes; [only Pages with over 400 likes are eligible to see the **Promote** button.](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=383437091692111)